Custom filter on Webix excelFilter
Please provide an example of how to create excelFilter filters based on the formatted text of a column, rather than the raw values. Currently, excelFilter filters based on the raw values, which results in duplicates in the multiselect list of the filter. We understand that excelFilter is based on the Filter UI as described here: https://docs.webix.com/desktop__filter.html

It would help to know the columnConfig you were using.  For example, are "options: []" provided to related the raw value to the display?
But since you've had no hints at all, here is what we do:  we copy the raw value to a fieldName_ov and place the display value into the data field that is actually being displayed by the grid.
This typescript function does the heavy lifting for us.  You'll notice that we actually create _dv and _ov "copies" of the data so we have both versions handy.  Performance for grids with around 5000 records has not been an issue.
export function propagateDisplayValues<T extends { '^DVPropagated'?:boolean, [key: string]: any; }>(data: T[]): T[] {
let isFirstDataRow: boolean = true; 
data.forEach((element) => {
    if (isFirstDataRow) {
        if (DVPropagatedFlagName in element && element[DVPropagatedFlagName]) {
            //tempting to return here if already true? but not a good idea for diffGram-based grids
            //return data;
        }
        else element[DVPropagatedFlagName] = true;
        isFirstDataRow = false;
    }
    Object.keys(element).forEach((key:string ) => {
        const dvName = `${key}_dv` as keyof T;
        const ovName = `${key}_ov` as keyof T;
        if (dvName in element) {
            if (!(ovName in element)) element[ovName] = element[key];
            element[key as keyof T] = element[dvName] ;
        }
    });
});
return data as T[];

}
